# connect an angular application to a server

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, api, express

I'm beginner in angular, I create my Nodeserver with Rest Crud APIs with my database Mysql, and I want to associate it with my project angular (ngx nebular), but I could not do it, thank you for helping me

this is app.js

```js
 var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var user=require('./model/user');
var api = require('./routes/api'); 

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/user',api);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to all GET request and send as only file your index.html which in fact should contain your Angular SPA. Something like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));    
});
```

You can have a look at the Express doc: http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: but i wonna connect my angular project to the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `mysql` library to access its functions. You also need to set a GET handler for the homepage, and assign the routes to it.

## 1) Bring in MySQL @ `app.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// ... other stuff here ...

// the mysql.createConnection function takes in a configuration object 
// this contains host, user, password and the database name.
const db = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'latelist'
});

// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});
global.db = db;
```

## 2) Route the yourHomepageFunction

In your case, we are already routing through `indexRouter.js` and it is important that this comes before step 3 in `app.js`.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

## 3) Assign GET handler for `/`

Finally, make sure you set a GET handler for the homepage somewhere in `app.js`, ala:

```
app.get('/', yourHomepageFunction);
```

For the sake of posterity, here's a sample of what `indexRouter.js` might look like:

```
module.exports = {
    yourHomepageFunction: (req, res) => {
        res.render("homepage.ejs", {
             // Stuff here such as passing title variables, etc
        });
    }
};
```